# "radially-extending" rod

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think I understand the meaning of
"radially-extending rod", which means "in a pattern of lines, etc. that go out from a central point towards the edge of a circle". However, I only see one line (rod) in the picture in the link. Am I missing something here ? Thank you.

"[An iron ring or ring clamp is an item of laboratory equipment which comprises a conjoined metal ring and radially-extending rod.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_ring_(laboratory)#:%7E:text=An%20iron%20ring%20or%20ring,of%20a%20laboratory%20clamp%20holder)"

Comment: ***a*** radially extending rod is ***one rod***. Just because you can't have just a single spoke on a bicycle wheel doesn't affect *this* context. The radius that's being "extended" is only "notional", because it doesn't come from the centre of the circle - there's a circular flask on the "inside", and the radial extension is effectively a handle. Same as the "radially-extended" handle on most circular saucepans.

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that definition of *radial*, but it is not a very good one.  *Radial* just means "along a radius", and does not necessarily have anything to do with a pattern of lines.